# Get image name from path

Tags: php, string

I´m searching solution for this:

I have a paths:

```
$PATH = images/large/Wildebeest-01.jpg
$PATH = images/large/greater-kudu-02.jpg
$PATH = images/large/BLUE-AND-YELLOW-MACAW-08.jpg
```

Which I need is this:

```
"Wildebeest"
"Greater kudu"
"Blue and yellow macaw"
```

i have a first part of the solution:

```
$PATH = $image;
$file = substr(strrchr($PATH, "/"), 1); 
echo  $file;
```

which gives me:

- Wildebeest-01.jpg
- greater-kudu-02.jpg
- BLUE-AND-YELLOW-MACAW-08.jpg

Could someone advise me, how to remove at least "-01.jpg" from the string?

Thanks!

Comment: substr($filename, -5);

Comment: What's the value of `$PATH`?

Comment: substr($filename, -5) >>>>  I  don´t need a last part of the string, this is not the solution, i need to remove the last part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it uses [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$arr = ["Wildebeest-01.jpg", "greater-kudu-02.jpg", "BLUE-AND-YELLOW-MACAW-08.jpg"];
foreach ($arr as $string) {
    $string = preg_replace("/-[^-]*$/", "", $string);
    $string = str_replace("-", " ", $string);
    $string = strtolower($string);
    var_dump($string);
}
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly thats what shows in their OP: _"Which I need is this:"_

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea for getting the file

```
$file = substr($PATH,strrpos($PATH, "/"));
```

Then to get rid of everything after the last `-` simply do.

```
$file = substr($file,0,strrpos($file,'-'));
```

Then turn `-` into .

```
$file = str_replace('-',' ',$file);
```

**EDIT**

If you don't care about possible changes in the future, like bigger numbers, different file extensions, and more.  You can simply do.

```
$file = substr($file,0,-5);
```

Comment: `Warning: substr() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in D:\PHP_SOURCE\tst.php` You gota test an answer not just guess at them

Comment: @RiggsFolly Whoops, typo.  Meant to type `strrpos` but for some reason typed `strrchr`.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with your solution..

```
$PATH = $image;
$file = substr(strrchr($PATH, "/"), 1); 

$op = preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z-]+).*/", "$1", $file);
$filename = trim( str_replace('-', '', $op); 
echo $filename; // outputs Wildebeest
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
$array = array();
$array[] = "images/large/Wildebeest-01.jpg";
$array[] = "images/large/greater-kudu-02.jpg";
$array[] = "images/large/BLUE-AND-YELLOW-MACAW-08.jpg";

function get_image_name($path) {
    $file = basename($path);
    if(preg_match("/(.*?)(-[0-9]*){0,1}([.][a-z]{3})/",$file,$reg)) {
        $file = $reg[1];
    }
    $file = ucfirst(strtolower(str_replace("-"," ",$file)));
    return $file;
}

foreach($array as $path) {
    echo "<br>".$path;
    echo " => ".get_image_name($path);
}
```

Output is:

```
images/large/Wildebeest-01.jpg => Wildebeest
images/large/greater-kudu-02.jpg => Greater kudu
images/large/BLUE-AND-YELLOW-MACAW-08.jpg => Blue and yellow macaw
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution, using preg_match().:

```
$getImageName = function ($path) {
   if (preg_match('/([\w\d-_]+)-\d+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i', $path, $matches)) {
       return ucwords(strtolower(str_replace(str_split('-_'), ' ', $matches[1])));
   }
   return false;
};

$paths = array(
   'images/large/Wildebeest-01.jpg',
   'images/large/greater-kudu-02.jpg',
   'images/large/BLUE-AND-YELLOW-MACAW-08.jpg',
);

$names = array_map($getImageName, $paths);


print_r($names);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Wildebeest
    [1] => Greater Kudu
    [2] => Blue And Yellow Macaw
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! Based on your answers, I found the perfect solution:

```
$filename = pathinfo($PATH);
$filename = $filename['filename'];
$filename = preg_replace("/-[^-]*$/", "", $filename);
$filename= ucfirst(strtolower(str_replace('-',' ',$filename)));
echo $filename;
```

Comment: In case the file name were using underscores instead of dashes to separate different words, I would do this inside strtolower():    str_replace(str_split('-_'), ' ', $filename);   Since str_replace accepts arrays with multiple characters to replace at once, and str_split() splits the string into array elements, you'll kill two birds with one stone.